# Async feature in Servlets

Tags: open-liberty, java-ee-8, servlet-3.1

I was just going back to `Servlet-3.x` features and exploring it. If I am not wrong, before Servlet-3.x it was thread per request model and it would run out of threads in the pool, for heavy incoming traffic.

So, with Servlet-3.x it says it is Asynchronous and doesn't keep the threads blocked , rather releases them immediately but just the task is delegated.

Here is my interpretation,

> consider there are 2 threads in Server thread-pool

For a new Async Servlet request `R1` there is a thread `T1`, this `T1` would delegate the task to `T2` and `T1` responds back to client immediately.

**Question:** Is `T2` created from Server thread-pool? If so, I don't get the point.

- Case 1: If it was old Synchronous Servlet request `T1` would have been busy running I/O task,
- Case 2: If it was Asynchronous Servlet call `T2` is busy running I/O task.
- In both cases, one of them is busy.

I tried to check the same with a sample Async servlet in `openliberty` app server, below is the sample log captured from my sample demo Servlet.

```
Entering doGet() == thread name is = Default Executor-thread-116
Exiting doGet() == thread name is = Default Executor-thread-116
=== Long running task started ===
Thread executing @start of long running task = Default Executor-thread-54
Thread executing @end of long running task = Default Executor-thread-54
=== Long running task ended ===
```

As shown above, the `Default Executor-thread-116` is released immediately and delegated long running task to the `Default Executor-thread-54`, but I am not sure if they are from the App Server thread pool. If so, why can't just `Default Executor-thread-116` do the task instead of delegation?

Can someone throw some light on this async behavior of Servlets in JavaEE

Answer (score 0):

In your example, where the work is synchronous and there's no separate executor/threadpool, there is nearly no point to use async servlets.   Lots of samples/examples out there are just block on a 2nd thread because they're trying to illustrate just the syntax.

But there's no reason why you can't spin off a thread to do a little work, add your async context to some list, and then after some event (inbound JMS, websocket, whatever) provides the data needed to complete the async response.  For example, a 2-player game server wouldn't wait for player 2 in a second thread, it would just have their async context floating around in memory waiting for a 2nd player to find it.